# Can we have space within a constant in Enum in Java

Tags: java

I need something like this

```
public enum SolutionType {
        RMS,
        CPA,
        BUSINESS DRIVERS,
        NA 
}
```

where BUSINESS DRIVERS is a value with space

Comment: Identifiers cannot be multiple words. It is customary to use an underscore (`_`) in this case.

Comment: Why do you need that? [Tell us about X.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java forbids the use of spaces in enums.

However you could use an underscore and implement a custom toString():

```
public enum SolutionType {
    RMS, CPA, BUSINESS_DRIVERS, NA;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name().replace("_", " ");
    }
}
```

Or just add a custom field to the enum:

```
public enum SolutionType {
    RMS, CPA, BUSINESS_DRIVERS("BUSINESS DRIVERS"), NA;

    private String readableName;

    private SolutionType() {
        this.readableName = this.name();
    }

    private SolutionType(String name) {
        this.readableName = name;
    }

    public String getReadableName() {
        return this.readableName;
    }
}
```

or a mix of the two...

```
public enum SolutionType {
    RMS, CPA, BUSINESS_DRIVERS("BUSINESS DRIVERS"), NA;

    private String readableName;

    private SolutionType() {
        this.readableName = this.name();
    }

    private SolutionType(String name) {
        this.readableName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.readableName;
    }
}
```